# mp3 http streaming : recording and playing simultaneosly

Tags: linux, http, streaming, mp3

I have a server (linux) program that generates audio files (mp3). What
I need is to broadcast these files using http stream. The tricky part
is that the broadcast starts when the file to be transmitted is not
fully generated.
I tried to do this using mpd+mpc but once I use the "mpc play" command
only already existing part of the file is buffered and transmitted,
and the player disregards the part that appears after beginning of
playback.
Is there any way to send a mp3 http stream (using mpd or any other
server-side player) so that the player won't stop the playback as it
reaches the end of the part that was buffered initially?
Any ideas, please.

Answer (score 0):

- http://streamripper.sourceforge.net/ can record and broadcast the same stream
- shotcast(or icecast, dont remember) was designed especially for this, and could re-encode your stream on the fly

Comment: Ok, I can try icecast and ices0 as stream source. But can't I do the same thing using built-in http streaming in mpd?

Comment: i dont know, not sure mpd was built for this. shoutcast is designed for transcoding & multiple listening simultaneous clients... you can try asking on mpd's mailing list if you really want to do that with mpd. btw, xmms2 also works something like mpd(as a daemon), it might also help you...